# Remove blank pages

Tags: includegraphics

If I try to include something via \includegraphics, I will sometimes get a blank space that goes away if I reduce the scale of the figure.

How can I avoid that?

Comment: the usual way is to put the `\includegraphics` in a `figure` enviornment, the purpose of `figure` is to allow the image to be moved to help avoid white space at page breaks.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If I do that, the image fits on the page for a much smaller scale than without

Comment: with no example posted it really is impossible to say anything, Try to make a small but complete example that shows the problem (you can use `example-image` as the image

Comment: `\newpage
\subsection{B) Lettre de motivation}
\noindent
\begin{figure}
\hspace*{-1.cm}
\includegraphics[scale = 0.7]{somepdf.pdf}
\end{figure} `

Comment: it really is impossible to say unless you make an example, perhaps you want the [htp] option to the figure. also the \noindent looks wrong